# How can I link my express server to generated 'dist' directory?

Tags: express, webpack, path

I am getting this error, "TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile"

```
root
  -dist
      |--index.html
      |--index_bundle.js
 
  -src
    |-server
        |-server.js
```

```js
//server.js
    var path = require('path')
    const express = require('express')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const cors = require('cors')

    const app = express()

    let dataStorage = {};

    app.use(cors())
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    }))

    app.use(express.static('dist'))

    app.listen(8081, function(){
      console.log('Server running on port 8081!')
    })

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile('../dist/index.html')    //need help setting this up
    })


    app.post('/formHandler', function(req, res){
    //post to dataStorage here
    })
```

I am trying to run an express server while also using webpack-dev-server for hot reloading.
I am having trouble with setting up the path to generated 'dist' file.

I am able to just run the webpack-dev-server without express and the file is working then.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have access to it by serving It's content as express static.

```
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist'));
```

You can also define the path at which statics assets can be accessible like this

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist'));
```

As in your dist folder there are already an `index.html` file it will be rendered by default when visiting the `/` path in your browser. No need to specify the `index.html` file in you request `URL`

Comment: This worked immediately, thank you very much, I will go learn about __dirname and express